# Display another view when a dropdown value is selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

-I know how to do it with modals(modalname.Show() but not views,
A nudge to the right direction is all I need.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {        
                $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
            
            //call another view
        
            
            }
```

Comment: It Is a Spa ...?

Comment: Pardon me? I dont understand your comment. I'm sorry :(

Comment: [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

Comment: It is a single page application? Do you need to change a div where app is rendered?

Comment: [Please search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp+jquery+call+another+view+dropdown+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Noted! No sir. it is a Message application and I'm trying to have separate views on log in, then search for a persons name and Inbox then another one to send a message when inbox name is selected.

Comment: If you mean a view within a multiview then I don't think you can do what you are trying because I don't believe the necessary html code for any view that is not the current view is generated to send to the client.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Let me suggest few. Let me know if none of them are useful to you.

**Scenario 1**: If it is partial view and you want to add to your page.

1.1: Add partial View (say name: _Pview.cshtml)

1.2: Add a div with id

```
<div id="add-pview"></div>
```

1.3: Through ajax, add the partial view to that id.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {        
                $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {            
                $.ajax({
                url: 'Controller/CallPView',
                type: 'POST',              
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#div-hist-report").html(data);
                 }
            });
                  }
```

1.4. In controller method:

```
public ActionResult CallPView()
{
    return PartialView("_Pview");
}
```

**Scenario 2**: If it a view, then you can give links as values to each option.

2.1. In View:

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="/Controller/View1">View1</option>
    <option value="/Controller/View2">View2</option>
</select>
```

2.2. In Controller function you need to add function to call the views:

```
public ActionResult View1()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult View2()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Scenario 3**: If you are using bootstrap then you don't even need javascript

3.1: In View:

```
<div class="dropdown show">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="" id="viewDD" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Select View
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="viewDD">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Controller/View1">View1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Controller/View2">View2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

2.2. In Controller function you need to add function to call the views:

```
public ActionResult View1()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult View2()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 possible solutions, depending on your Scenario.

**Scenario 1**
Your views is in different divs and the switch happens client side only

1. Add dropdown as follow :

```
    @Html.DropDownList("dropdown",
    new SelectListItem[]
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "View 1", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "View 2", Value = "2" }
    })
```

2. Add Divs with different names and one is hidden

```
    <div id="View1">
        View 1
    </div>
    <div id="View2" hidden>
        View 2
    </div>
```

3. Use the following Javascript to show and hide depending on the selection

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dropdown").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem == "1") {
                $("#View1").show();
                $("#View2").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#View1").hide();
                $("#View2").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

**Scenario 2** When you need to go fetch the view from the server

1. Add dropdown as follow :

```
    @Html.DropDownList("dropdown",
    new SelectListItem[]
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "View 1", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "View 2", Value = "2" }
    })
```

2. Add one div with an id

```
    <div id="myView">

    </div>
```

3. Add 2 partial views mine will be called "_view1.cshtml" and "_view2.cshtml"
4. Add Action in your controller to accept the selected option as parameter and return the partial view as seen below.

```
    public ActionResult GetView(int selectedItem)
    {
        if (selectedItem == 1)
        {
            return PartialView("_view1");
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_view2");
        }
    }
```

5. Use the below Javascript to replace the content of the div with what's returned from the server

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dropdown").change(function () {
                var selectedItem = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetView", "Home")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                    data: { selectedItem: selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#myView").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            });
            });
        });
```